# Standard topology generated by the basis whose elements are open intervals of rationals

Tags: general-topology

> Proposition:
>
> The collection $\mathbf{B'}$ of intervals $\left ( a,b \right ) \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, where a and b are both rational, is a basis for the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}$.

I don't quite understand the proof for this.
In particular, the part

> What needs to be shown is that the topology T' it generates is precisely the topology T generated by $\mathbf{B}$ for the standard topology.
> In other words, for any $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, we have $U \in T'$ IFF $U \in T$

Can anyone perhaps clarify this statement?

Answer (score 1):

The text assumes you know what the standard topology on $\Bbb R$ is, and that there is a standard choice of basis for this topology. Call this basis $B$, and the topology it generates $T$. The given basis $B'$ also generates a topology, call it $T'$. Now, it could be, and this is indeed what the proof is about, that $T=T'$. In that case, their elements coincide, i. e. $U\in T\Leftrightarrow U\in T'$, where $U\subset \Bbb R$.

The text will then proceed to prove this statement, presumably.

Answer (score 1):

Proof sketch / hint: For any basis interval $(x,y) \in \mathbf B$ (so, $x,y \in \mathbb R$), find a sequence $r_i$ of rationals that converge from above to $x$, and a sequence $s_i$ of rationals that converge from below to $y$, take the family of intervals $\{(r_i, s_i)\}_{i \in \mathbb N}$, take the union of that family. This will show that $\mathbf B'$ generates $\mathbf B$.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question, which is asking us to elaborate on a certain (short) piece of text. The question does not ask us to provide a (hint at a) proof.

Answer (score 0):

One way to show that topologies $T$ and $T'$ on a set $X$ are identical is to exhibit a base $B$ for $T$ and a base $B'$ for $T',$ such that, for each $x\in X,$ we have

(i) whenever $x\in b\in B$ there exists $b'\in B'$ with $x\in b'\subset b$

(ii) whenever $x\in b'\in B'$ there exists $b\in B$ with $x\in b\subset b'.$

When $T$ is the usual topology on $\mathbb R$, let $B$ be the set of intervals $(u,u')$ for all  $u,u'\in R$ with $u<u'.$ Let T' be the topology generated by the base   $B'$  of intervals $(q,q')$ for all $q,q'\in \mathbb Q$ with $q<q'.$

(i). If $x\in b=(u,u')\in B,$ there exists $q\in [u,x)\cap \mathbb Q$ and $q'\in (x,u']\cap \mathbb Q.$ Then $b'=(q,q')\in B'$ and $x\in b'\subset b.$

(ii). If $x\in b'=(q,q')\in B'$ then $b'\in B$ so let $b=b',$ and we have $x\in b\subset b'.$